# JQuery click event is not captured in Firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox, jquery-click-event

Got HTML with few of these(sometimes 4, sometimes 15:

```
<button type="button">
<img class="bv-image-wrapper" src="http://lsco.scene7.com/..">
</button>
```

and

```
$('.bv-image-wrapper').click(function(event) {
   alert('blah blah');
});
```

It works fine on all browsers except FireFox.  No errors in the console. Breakpoint inside the click handler is not hit. I am going mad. Please help

Comment: Why are you binding a click handler to an element that is inside a button rather than to the button itself?

Comment: button is provided by 3rd party vendor. they handle button click. Image is to change the look of it according to my company's standards. Image Click event handler is added for tracking/analytics purposes.